# Please verify that this expression is written correctly

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following expression that is supposed to convert months into quarters.  However, when I run the report, only the first and fourth quarter show up.  Could someone please take a look at my expression to see if it is correct?  I have never created an SSRS report or expression before.

```
=IIf(Fields!Month.Value/3 <= 1, 1, IIf(Fields!Month.Value/3 > 1 AND Fields!Month.Value <=2, 2, IIf(Fields!Month.Value > 2 and Fields!Month.Value <= 3, 3, 4)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `Fields!Month.Value` is 4. That gives:

```
=IIf(4/3 <= 1, 1, IIf(4/3 > 1 AND 4 <=2, 2, IIf(4 > 2 and 4 <= 3, 3, 4)))
```

Obviously, `4/3 <= 1` is false, `4/3 > 1 AND 4 <=2` is false, and `4 > 2 and 4 <= 3` is false, meaning that the quarter is 4. Incorrect.

Try this:

```
int((Fields!Month.Value - 1) / 3) + 1
```

Comment: Wow was I off.  That did it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using `=DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, Fields!Month.Value)`?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=IIF((Fields!Month.Value/3)<=1,1,
  (IIF((Fields!Month.Value/3)<=2,2,
      (IIF((Fields!Month.Value/3)<=3,3,4)))))
```